# Why does maven filter resources?

Tags: maven, resources, filtering

I know that variables are included in the resources and they come from the system properties according to the Maven manual but why does we need this filtering and what kind of problem does Maven solve by doing this?

Comment: Filtering is only done [if you activate it](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). The question is what exactly is your problem or what do don't understand ?

Comment: My question is what does it what really happens when we filter the resources? What problem does filtering solve if we activate it ?

Comment: The problem it solves is if you have a property files or other files which need to be seeded with information from your project simple example the version number of your project. This can be done using placeholders like '${project.version}'  etc.

Comment: A very good question. +1. I had read the chapter on filtering in Maven manual, and it says nothing about what it filters, why it filters and I doubt it filters anything.